# Targeting .NET Framework 4.0

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I just downloaded MSVS 2010 from university MSDN AA. The IDE itself is wonderful, I can't complain, but...

I'm developing  project that combines C#, C++/CLI and C++ (native core, cli bridge DLL and c# GUI). But the VS 2010 seems *NOT TO* support targeting .NET for C++/CLI projects unless VS 2008 is installed. Requiring both VS 2010 and 2008 installed is in my opinion kind of unreasonable for open-source project. Thee only other solution is targeting .NET 4.0.

**Do you think it is already time to start releasing applications requiring .NET 4.0**? Couldn't it deter potential users since it is so new and not yet exactly wide-spread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why it's too soon, users can download it easily and they're gonna have to download it eventually anyway right?